# App Link iOS Url parameter: Facebook Sahre

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the doc over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) it is stated to define meta tags as:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
<meta property="al:ios:al:ios:app_store_id content="12345" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
```

In the above meta tags I'm able to identify app_store_id and app_name but what about the url, from where could I get the url content?

Do we have to write down the url that is shared on fb lets say...

```
www.domain.com/books/212
```

Comment: _“The `url` property must match a custom scheme that you've defined in your app's `.plist` file.”_

Comment: In My .plist I have defined: com.appname.mobile

Comment: But I suppose the format should be somewhat- "example://applinks". So how will the url be in my case ?

Comment: Any luck in this?  I am having the same concern